# How to join 2 Docker commands to one?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I read an instruction here

https://github.com/dahlsailrunner/northwind-core-api

and exec 2 commands everytime as it is written:

```
docker volume create --name northwind-pg-data -d local
docker-compose -f .\docker-compose-windows.yml up
```

But is it possible to add the 1st command to the docker-compose-windows.yml file and perform one command only?

There is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: northwind
      POSTGRES_USER: northwind_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: thewindisblowing
    volumes:
      - northwind-pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./northwind.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/northwind.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  northwind-pg-data:
    external: true
```

Comment: Normally `docker-compose up` will create the named volumes shown in the top-level `volumes:` block; you shouldn't usually need to manually `docker volume create` anything.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  What happens if you don't manually create the volume?

Comment: It seems you are right. I have added the docker-compose file (see above) and it contains the volume commands.